# Can I only read the title?

Tags: discussion, question-titles

A question post on Mi Yodeya has both a title and a body. When determining if an answer addresses the question asked, is it sufficient to look only at the title or must the title be taken in the context of the body of the question to understand what the asker actually sought? After all, not all the relevant details can always fit in a short title.

Comment: similar https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4191/759

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66120

Comment: @Shmuel Thank you. I believe that conforms with what we practice on Mi Yodeya as described in the "similar" link above.

Comment: Yes. the body often gives context to the question one asks.

Comment: I'm tempted to post an answer along the lines of "Of course you can only read the title, if that's what you want to do. We can't dictate what parts of posts you read." But I won't.

Answer (score 8):

The latter. And you'd only get that if you read the question post.

Don't judge a book by its cover.

Comment: I believe this represents standing site policy.

Answer (score 0):

In the main I agree with DoubleAA's answer (already upvoted). But it's important to take the whole post as a whole. Therefore, if the title has a question in it, then the question in the title should absolutely match the question in the body (as far as possible!).

If the question's title doesn't match the question in the body, then it can give rise to problems. In that case it's essentially unclear what OP is asking, and the question should be edited and improved.

To be clear, I am not talking about posts like  [Removing (metal) nails on Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/137939/removing-metal-nails-on-shabbat) or [Abraham's female partners](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/137940/abrahams-female-partners). The question is as presented, in the body of the post, and the title is just that, a title.

But picture this:

> **Is beaver-meat kosher?**
> After all, the catholics declared it okay to eat beaver during lent. Plus the Tanakh never mentions beavers which means it's allowed right? the same as black pudding?

There are all sorts of problems with this question. I would be inclined to vote for closure or have it edited. But on the other hand, it has exactly one answerable, and it's in the title. So there should be some wiggle-room in this policy, especially in the case of low-quality questions.

Comment: I think that this is a very important point about post quality. In any case, if you want to post an answer, you need to read and understand the title and body of the question post. If either of them needs improvement, helping improve them could be a great first step before answering.